# Initial Value for an ODE Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE

$\mathbf{A}\dfrac{d\vec{y}}{dt}+\mathbf{B}\vec{y}=\vec{x}$,

where $\vec{y}$ and $\vec{x}$ are $n\times1$ vectors and are functions of $t$, and $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are $n\times n$ matrices. $\mathbf{A}$ is a diagonal matrix and $\mathbf{B}$ is a sparse positive definite matrix.

Knowing the value of $\vec{y}(0)$ and the value of $\vec{x}(t)$ over $t\in[0,t_0]$, how can I determine $\vec{y}(t_0)$ efficiently? Please note that $\vec{x}$ may vary dramatically over $[0,t_0]$. My initial thinking is that averaging $\vec{x}$ over $[0,t_0]$ and simply solving the ODE with the given initial condition does not yield a proper value for $\vec{y}(t_0)$. Moreover, $t_0$ might be significantly larger than $0$.

The real problem that I have is a numerical problem, so I do not mind if the answer comprises of using numerical techniques to solve ODEs.

Comment: Is $A$ invertible?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbf{A}$ is a diagonal matrix and $\mathbf{B}$ is positive definite.